# There is a way to sort columns without using the built in sort function?

Tags: vba, excel

I pretty much want VBA to do the following

1) Cut the selected row

2) Insert the row in the correct spot, in alphabetic order (based on col C)

The reason I cant use sort is because I have tons of references to the one sheet and when I use sort, it messed up all the references, even though they all have $ in them. I have found that cutting will do the trick though

Comment: How how may rows are in the range you want to sort?  And what kind of data (Number, Text or Date) is in the key columns?

Comment: A variable amount, no more than 100 though. It is just text, I want it alphabetical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the macro below meets your requirement.

Constant `ColSort` defines the sort column which I have set to C.  Constant `RowDataFirst` defines the first data row.  My test data has two heading rows.  Change the value of `RowDataFirst` as necessary.

I have only sorted one test worksheet but I believe the macro will work for any number of rows and columns.

I sort from worksheet "SortSrc" to "SortDest".  The names of these worksheets are defined by constants `WkShtNameDest` and `WkShtNameSrc`.  Change these constants as required.

I have included a VBA implementation of shell sort.  This is not considered to be the best sort but I had the routine to hand and you will not be sorting enough data for it to matter.

It creates an array containing the values of column C and the row numbers.  I sort this index array.  I use the sorted index array to control the copying of data from the source worksheet to the destination.

I hope I have included enough comments.  Come back with questions if necessary.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SortByCutNPaste()

  Const ColSort As String = "C"
  Const RowDataFirst As Long = 3
  Const WkShtNameDest As String = "SortDest"
  Const WkShtNameSrc As String = "SortSrc"

  Dim ColMax As Long
  Dim InxSort As Long
  Dim SortArray() As String
  Dim RangeDest As Range
  Dim RangeSrc As Range
  Dim RowDestCrnt As Long
  Dim RowMax As Long
  Dim RowSrcCrnt As Long

  With Sheets(WkShtNameSrc)
    ' Find the maximum used row and maximum used column
    RowMax = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    ColMax = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
  End With

  ' Size sort array so one entry per data row
  ReDim SortArray(1 To RowMax - RowDataFirst + 1)

  ' Build sort array with each entry containing:
  '   Value of column C     Nul     Row number padded to three digits

  ' The Nul is used as a low value in case any cell value ends in what looks
  ' like a row number.  For example:
  '   Row 1  Value ABC001
  '   Row 2  Value ABC
  ' would give sort keys ABC001001 and ABC002 which would be sorted incorrectly.
  ' Keys ABC001(0)001 and ABC(0)002 will sort incorrectly.

  ' Use LCase(.Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColSort).Value) if you want a case insensitive sort.

  ' I have padded row numbers to three digits since you say you have 100 rows.

  InxSort = LBound(SortArray)
  With Sheets(WkShtNameSrc)
    For RowSrcCrnt = RowDataFirst To RowMax
      SortArray(InxSort) = .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColSort).Value & _
                           Chr(0) & Right("000" & RowSrcCrnt, 3)
      InxSort = InxSort + 1
    Next
  End With

  ' Sort array
  Call ShellSort(SortArray, UBound(SortArray))

  ' Prepare destination worksheet

  With Sheets(WkShtNameDest)
    ' Clear any existing contents
    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
  End With

  ' Copy column widths
  With Sheets(WkShtNameSrc)
    .Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy
  End With
  With Sheets(WkShtNameDest)
    .Rows(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
                          SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
  End With

'  For InxSort = LBound(SortArray) To UBound(SortArray)
'    Debug.Print SortArray(InxSort)
'  Next

  ' Copy heading rows from source to destination
  ' Note source and destination row numbers are the same
  ' so use RowSrcCrnt for both worksheets.
  For RowSrcCrnt = 1 To RowDataFirst - 1
    With Sheets(WkShtNameSrc)
      Set RangeSrc = .Range(.Cells(RowSrcCrnt, 1), .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColMax))
    End With
    With Sheets(WkShtNameDest)
      Set RangeDest = .Range(.Cells(RowSrcCrnt, 1), .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColMax))
    End With
    RangeSrc.Copy Destination:=RangeDest
  Next

  ' Copy data rows in index sequence
  RowDestCrnt = RowDataFirst
  For InxSort = LBound(SortArray) To UBound(SortArray)

    RowSrcCrnt = Val(Right(SortArray(InxSort), 3))
    With Sheets(WkShtNameSrc)
      Set RangeSrc = .Range(.Cells(RowSrcCrnt, 1), .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColMax))
    End With
    With Sheets(WkShtNameDest)
      Set RangeDest = .Range(.Cells(RowDestCrnt, 1), .Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColMax))
    End With
    RangeSrc.Copy Destination:=RangeDest
    RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 1
  Next

End Sub
Public Sub ShellSort(ByRef arrstgTgt() As String, ByVal inxLastToSort As Integer)

  ' Converted by Tony Dallimore in 2005 from Pascal routine in "Algorithms"
  ' by Robert Sedgewick (2nd edition) published 1989 by Addison-Wesley.

  '   The most basic sort is the insertion sort in which adjacent elements are compared
  ' and swapped as necessary.  This can be very slow if the smallest elements are at
  ' end.  ShellSort is a simple extension which gains speed by allowing exchange of
  ' elements that are far apart.
  '   The idea is to rearrange the file to give it the property that taking every h-th
  ' element (starting anywhere) yields a sorted file.  Such a file is said to be
  ' h-sorted.  Put another way, an h-sorted file is h independent sorted files,
  ' interleaved together.  By h-sorting for large value of H, we can move elements
  ' in the array long distances and thus make it easier to h-sort for smaller values of
  ' h.  Using such a procedure for any sequence of values of h which ends in 1 will
  ' produce a sorted file.
  '   This program uses the increment sequence: ..., 1093, 364, 121, 40, 13, 4, 1.  This
  ' is known to be a good sequence but cannot be proved to be the best.
  '   The code looks faulty but it is not.  The inner loop compares an
  ' entry with the previous in the sequence and if necessary moves it back down the
  ' sequence to its correct position.  It does not continue with the rest of the sequence
  ' giving the impression it only partially sorts a sequence.  However, the code is not
  ' sorting one sequence then the next and so on.  It examines the entries in element
  ' number order.  Having compared an entry against the previous in its sequence, it will
  ' be intH loops before the next entry in the sequence in compared against it.

  ' arrstgTgt      The array to be sorted.
  ' inxLastToSort  Elements lbound(arrstgTgt) to inxLastToSort are to be sorted.

  Dim intNumRowsToSort          As Integer
  Dim intLBoundAdjust           As Integer
  Dim intH                      As Integer
  Dim inxRowA                   As Integer
  Dim inxRowB                   As Integer
  Dim inxRowC                   As Integer
  Dim stgTemp                   As String

  'Dim intComps                  As Integer
  'Dim intSwaps                  As Integer

  intNumRowsToSort = inxLastToSort - LBound(arrstgTgt) + 1
  intLBoundAdjust = LBound(arrstgTgt) - 1

  ' Set intH to 1, 4, 13, 40, 121, ..., 3n+1, ... until intH > intNumRowsToSort
  intH = 1
  Do While intH <= intNumRowsToSort
    intH = 3 * intH + 1
  Loop

  Do While True
    If intH = 1 Then Exit Do
    ' The minimum value on entry to this do-loop will be 4 so there is at least
    ' one repeat of the loop.
    intH = intH \ 3
    For inxRowA = intH + 1 To intNumRowsToSort
      stgTemp = arrstgTgt(inxRowA + intLBoundAdjust)
      inxRowB = inxRowA
      Do While True
        ' The value of element inxRowA has been saved.  Now move the element intH back
        ' from row inxRowA into this row if it is smaller than the saved value.  Repeat
        ' this for earlier elements until one is found that is larger than the saved
        ' value which is placed in the gap.
        inxRowC = inxRowB - intH
        If arrstgTgt(inxRowC + intLBoundAdjust) <= stgTemp Then Exit Do
        arrstgTgt(inxRowB + intLBoundAdjust) = arrstgTgt(inxRowC + intLBoundAdjust)
        inxRowB = inxRowC
        If inxRowB <= intH Then Exit Do
      Loop
      arrstgTgt(inxRowB + intLBoundAdjust) = stgTemp
    Next
  Loop

End Sub
```